# Happy birthday method -- simple way

Tags: ruby

Can I make the second method of code simpler by incorporating the first method into my second method?

```
def happy_birthday(birthday_kids)
  # add your code snippet here!
  birthday_kids.each do |kids_name, age|
    puts "Happy Birthday #{kids_name}! You are now #{age} years old!"
  end
end

def age_appropriate_birthday(birthday_kids)
  birthday_kids.each do |kid,age|
    if age < 13 
      puts "Happy Birthday #{kid}! You are now #{age} years old!"
    else
      puts "You are too old for this."
    end 
  end 
end
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please investigate what tags are defined as rather than attach them willie-nillie. [tag:happy] is a YACC parser generator for the Hascal language, which has nothing to do with your question.

Comment: Oh sorry! I was going to delete that but got distracted and forgot to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like a small modification to the second method would do what you want.

```
def happy_birthday(birthday_kids, age_appropriate = false)
  birthday_kids.each do |kid,age|
    if (age < 13 || !age_appropriate) 
      puts "Happy Birthday #{kid}! You are now #{age} years old!"
    else
      puts "#{kid} you are too old for this."
    end 
  end 
end
```

If this method were part of a class,  the class itself could hold the info as to how it should greet.

```
class BirthdayGreeter
  def initialize(age_appropriate = false)
    @age_appropriate = age_appropriate
  end

  def happy_birthday(birthday_kids)
    birthday_kids.each do |kid,age|
      if (age < 13 || !@age_appropriate) 
        puts "Happy Birthday #{kid}! You are now #{age} years old!"
      else
        puts "#{kid} you are too old for this."
      end
    end 
  end 
end


greeter = BirthdayGreeter.new
greeter_age_appropriate = BirthdayGreeter.new(true)

greeter.happy_birthday(kids)
greeter_age_appropriate.happy_birthday(kids)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I am new to learning ruby and wanted to see how to incorporate methods together for simplicity and this helped out a lot.

Answer (score 0):

There are a number of ways to do it.

One way, which changes only one line of code, is this:

```
if age < 13 
  happy_birthday([[kid, age]].to_h)
```

This works because a hash `{name => age}` is interchangable with an array of tuples `[[name, age]]` for the purposes of iteration.

Another approach which is a little more idiomatic would be to use [`Enumerable#partition`](https://apidock.com/ruby/Enumerable/partition):

```
def age_appropriate_birthday(birthday_kids)
  young, old = birthday_kids.parititon { |name, age| age < 13 }
  happy_birthday(young)
  old.each { |name, age| puts "#{kid} you are too old for this." }
end
```

I'm assuming that you don't want to modify your `happy_birthday` method. If you are ok with doing that, then the approach given by nPn works also.